# AWS ECS How to communicate with a container from another container in same bridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, linux-containers

I am using AWS ECS, i have a cluster with some containers in bridge mode, i want to connect to a container from another container, in same cluster,  can i connect using a name ? and if so which name i should use ?  thanks.

Comment: If they're on the same task, you can connect over localhost. Otherwise, something like this might be useful: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/service-discovery-for-amazon-ecs-using-dns/

Comment: Thanks for replying , i cannot find a documentation in aws about resolving names in bridge mode, as my ECS clusters are running in bridge, so i am not sure if i can contact the other containers using name in task or not, seems i should try and see, i will do and update you, thanks again.